# How to read back XML data from memory stream

Tags: c#, xml

I want to write an object (using XmlDictionaryWriter) to memory stream and read it back. I have the following code. When I read back the object from Memory Stream it crashes. The crash message is: Additional information: There was an error deserializing the object of type Obj_4_1_Perform_IO_Operations.FullName. The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

```
[DataContract]
public class FullName
{
    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }              
    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FullName fn = new FullName();
        fn.LastName = "John";
        fn.LastName = "Doe";
        MemoryStream ms = Process(fn);
        Console.WriteLine("Read Back");
        ms.Position = 0;
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(FullName));
        FullName fn2 = (FullName)serializer.ReadObject(ms); //<--- crash here      
        Console.WriteLine("Deserialized record: {0} {1}", fn2.FirstName, fn2.LastName);
    }
    public static MemoryStream Process(FullName name)
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var binary = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter(ms);
        var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(FullName));
        ser.WriteObject(binary, name);
        binary.Flush();
        Console.WriteLine("MemoryStream is {0} bytes long", ms.Length);
        return ms;
    }
}
```

Comment: What sort of 'crash'?  Look for the exception details and stacktrace. Always include those in a question.

Comment: Exception message: There was an error deserializing the object of type Obj_4_1_Perform_IO_Operations.FullName. The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Comment: Good. Now edit that into the question.